# Algorithm about sum of powers

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on the question shown below, part 2. However when I implement it in python, it fails with "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".
[image]

Here's my algorithm:

```
import math
def sumofpowers2(x):
    count = 1
    if math.isclose(x ** count,0,rel_tol=0.001):
        return 0
    count += 1
    return 1 + x * sumofpowers2(x)

print(sumofpowers2(0.8))
```

Edited.

Comment: You can show the picture by putting an exclamation mark in front of the square brakets.

Comment: Did you expect the new value of `count` to be carried over to the next invocation of `sumofpowers2`? It does not. Maybe you meant `def sumofpowers2(x, count=1):`?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, `sumofpowers2(x)` calls itself with the same argument, resulting in infinite recursion (unless the `if` condition is true right from the start, it will never be true).

Every time `sumofpowers2()` calls itself, a new variable called `count` gets created and set to `1`. To make this code work, you need to figure out a way to carry the value of `count` across calls.

Comment: There is a base case in there though

Comment: @harold: If the base case condition isn't satisfied right away, it will never be satisfied (since `x` never changes).

Comment: Or count could change, but it doesn't either. It kind of looks like that was supposed to happen though

Comment: @harold: Oh, you're right, I didn't see the count. I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, please learn basic debugging: add a simple `print` to track your values just before you depend on them:

```
def sumofpowers2(x):
    count = 1
    print(x, count, x**count)
    if math.isclose(x ** count,0,rel_tol=0.001):
        ...
```

Output:

```
(0.8, 1, 0.8)
(0.8, 1, 0.8)
(0.8, 1, 0.8)
...
```

This points up the critical problem: you reset `count` to 1 every time you enter the routine.  The simple fix is to hoist the initialization outside the loop:

```
count = 1

def sumofpowers2(x):
    global count
    print(x, count, x**count)
    if math.isclose(x ** count,0,rel_tol=0.001):
```

Output:

```
0.8 1 0.8
0.8 2 0.6400000000000001
0.8 3 0.5120000000000001
0.8 4 0.4096000000000001
0.8 5 0.3276800000000001
0.8 6 0.2621440000000001
0.8 7 0.20971520000000007
0.8 8 0.1677721600000001
0.8 9 0.13421772800000006
0.8 10 0.10737418240000006
0.8 11 0.08589934592000005
0.8 12 0.06871947673600004
0.8 13 0.054975581388800036
0.8 14 0.043980465111040035
0.8 15 0.03518437208883203
0.8 16 0.028147497671065624
0.8 17 0.022517998136852502
0.8 18 0.018014398509482003
0.8 19 0.014411518807585602
0.8 20 0.011529215046068483
0.8 21 0.009223372036854787
0.8 22 0.00737869762948383
0.8 23 0.005902958103587064
0.8 24 0.004722366482869652
0.8 25 0.0037778931862957215
0.8 26 0.0030223145490365774
0.8 27 0.002417851639229262
0.8 28 0.0019342813113834097
0.8 29 0.0015474250491067279
0.8 30 0.0012379400392853823
0.8 31 0.0009903520314283058
4.993810299803575
```

Better yet, make `count` an added parameter to your function:

```
def sumofpowers2(x, count):
    print(x, count, x**count)
    if math.isclose(x ** count,0,rel_tol=0.001):
        return 0
    return 1 + x * sumofpowers2(x, count+1)
```

Not that your cascaded arithmetic is not the value you expect.